# elasticsearch is taking time while doing update and search simultaneously

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm doing update in elasticsearch document and the same time one rest api is calling for search results. Below is my code.

```
public String updateElasticsearchDocument(String index, String type, List<String> indexID) {
    Client client = ESClientFactory.getInstance();
    UpdateResponse updateResponse = null;
    JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject json =new JSONObject();
    int i=1;

    try {
        for(String id : indexID)
        {   
         updateResponse = client.prepareUpdate(index, type, id)
                          .setDoc(jsonBuilder()
                                  .startObject().field("view_mode", "read")
                                  .endObject())
                                .setDocAsUpsert(true)
                                .setFields("_source")
                          .execute().actionGet();
         logger.info("updating the document for type= "+ updateResponse.getType()+ " for id= "+ updateResponse.getId());

         json.put("indexID"+i, updateResponse.getId());
         i++;
        }       
        jsonResponse.put("updated_index", json);

    } catch (ActionRequestValidationException e) {
        logger.warn(this.getClass().getName() + ":" + "updateDocument: "
                        + e.getMessage(), e);
    } 
    catch (ElasticsearchException e) {
        logger.warn(this.getClass().getName() + ":" + "updateDocument: "
                        + e.getMessage(), e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn(this.getClass().getName() + ":" + "updateDocument: "
                + e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonResponse.toString();
}
```

Search query I'm pusing is here

```
POST /monitoring/quota-management/_search

    {
          "query": {"match": {
              "view_mode": "read"
           }}, 
        "sort": [
           {
              "_timestamp": {
                 "order": "desc"
              }
           }
        ],
        "size": 10
    }
```

Now there is time gap between these 2 requests, I have to wait for like 40-50 seconds to get the updated search result. This is affecting the production application. Please let me know what needs to be done here to minimizes the time taken

-Subhadip

Comment: what is the refresh interval for you index ? you can try using http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html#indices-refresh  explicitly and see if that helps

Comment: I gave "refresh_interval": "30s". How much it should be ?

Comment: the default is 1s i think you can keep it the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the data to be indexed immediately, you could set the refresh on update like this:

client.prepareUpdate(index, type, id).setRefresh(true).setDoc(...).execute().actionGet();

Just know that there are tradeoffs to doing this if you update very frequently. Indexing can eat up a lot of IO/cpu.

A good middle ground would be to set the refresh interval to a reasonable interval.